# How to show submenu product list on menu product list?

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products

[image: my menu and submenu]

This is my menu and submenu on backend. But in the front end view, I don't see my "Powerbank" product list on  "Aksesoris Handphone" product list.

How can I show my "Powerbank" product list on "Aksesoris Handphone" too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check on "Aksesoris Handphone" category Display Settings tab:

- **Is Anchor : Yes**

All product of sub category of "Aksesoris Handphone" category will be display

If you want to display only "Powerbank" product list on "Aksesoris Handphone"
you can add "Powerbank" 's product to "Aksesoris Handphone" category at **Category Product** tab

[This post](http://www.magedevelopers.com/blog/magento-tutorials/what-is-anchor/) show more infomation about **Is Anchor**

Hope this helpful!

Comment: Thankyou dat tran